# Can someone explain to me this question in C

Tags: boolean-expression, boolean-algebra

Been trying to figure out this stuff. This has to do with boolean algebra and is suing the C language. It has some algebra in it. Not sure how this works. Been trying to figure this out for half hour

**Simplify the following Boolean expressions.**

```
a.            F = A*B*C*D + A*B*C*D + A*B*C*D + A*B*C*D

b.            F = A*B*C + A*B*C + A*C*D + A*B*C*D
```

Comment: This isn't a programming question, nor does it have anything to do with C. This is a logical operations question.

Comment: What does this boolean algebra question has to do with C and SO?

Comment: Please do not upload screenshots of the problem: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: First create a new "variable" for `A AND B AND C AND D`, lets call it `X`. Then use that variable in the first expression, and you will have something like `X OR X OR X OR X`. Now how do you think that could be simplified?

Comment: I think that you should ask it in some boolean algebra forum. This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in boolean algebra `+` is `OR` you can simplify it with:

```
F = A*B*C*D + A*B*C*D + A*B*C*D + A*B*C*D    (A v A) = A
  = A*B*C*D + A*B*C*D + A*B*C*D              (A v A) = A
  = A*B*C*D + A*B*C*D                        (A v A) = A
  = A*B*C*D                                  (A v A) = A   

F = A*B*C + A*B*C + A*C*D + A*B*C*D          (A v A) = A
  = A*B*C + A*C*D + A*B*C*D
  = A*B*C + A*C*D 
  = A*C*(B + D)
```

Comment: `A*C*D + A*B*C*D` =`A*C*D` btw

Comment: Edit my post if i did something wrong, thank you!

Comment: Done. I think the last two lines are correct- please check

Comment: Thanks guys! I appreciate it

Comment: @EdHeal I think it's ok! Thank you for your correction.